# Pandas to JSON output in an object specific

Tags: python, json, dictionary, pandas

Please I need assistance from anyone to format the output of the json file. Thanks 
**The expected output**

```
{
    "2001-02-17": [
        {"ArCiCo": "Paris_France", "AuthorID": "CCC", "DptCiCo": "Tokyo_Japan"}
    ], 
    "2001-03-03": [
        {"ArCiCo": "London_UK", "AuthorID": "EEE", "DptCiCo": "Berlin_Germany"}
    ], 
    "2001-03-10": [
        {"ArCiCo": "Lagos_Nigeria", "AuthorID": "BBB", "DptCiCo": "London_UK"}, 
        {"ArCiCo": "Tokyo_Japan", "AuthorID": "CCC", "DptCiCo": "NewYork_US"}, 
        {"ArCiCo": "Nairobi_Kenya", "AuthorID": "DDD", "DptCiCo": "NewYork_US"}
    ], 
    "2001-03-12": [
        {"ArCiCo": "Paris_France", "AuthorID": "AAA", "DptCiCo": "NewYork_US"}
    ], 
    "2001-04-08": [
        {"ArCiCo": "Paris_France", "AuthorID": "EEE", "DptCiCo": "London_UK"}
    ], 
    "2001-04-10": [
        {"ArCiCo": "NewYork_US", "AuthorID": "AAA", "DptCiCo": "Tokyo_Japan"}
    ]
}
```

Currently this is the output, I have ***double-quote*** (" ") before { and after } and I have each value in a ***single quote*** ('  '). I want the output to look like that expected output.

```
{
    "2001-02-17": [
        **"**{'ArCiCo': 'Paris_France', 'AuthorID': 'CCC', 'DptCiCo': 'Tokyo_Japan'}**"**
    ], 
    "2001-03-03": [
        "{'ArCiCo': 'London_UK', 'AuthorID': 'EEE', 'DptCiCo': 'Berlin_Germany'}"
    ], 
    "2001-03-10": [
        "{'ArCiCo': 'Lagos_Nigeria', 'AuthorID': 'BBB', 'DptCiCo': 'London_UK'}", 
        "{'ArCiCo': 'Tokyo_Japan', 'AuthorID': 'CCC', 'DptCiCo': 'NewYork_US'}", 
        "{'ArCiCo': 'Nairobi_Kenya', 'AuthorID': 'DDD', 'DptCiCo': 'NewYork_US'}"
    ], 
    "2001-03-12": [
        "{'ArCiCo': 'Paris_France', 'AuthorID': 'AAA', 'DptCiCo': 'NewYork_US'}"
    ], 
    "2001-04-08": [
        "{'ArCiCo': 'Paris_France', 'AuthorID': 'EEE', 'DptCiCo': 'London_UK'}"
    ], 
    "2001-04-10": [
        "{'ArCiCo': 'NewYork_US', 'AuthorID': 'AAA', 'DptCiCo': 'Tokyo_Japan'}"
    ]
}
```

This is the sample code that produced the output

```
json_dict[date_range]= [str(v) for v in dup_date.to_dict(orient='records')]
```

Comment: Have you tried `to_json()`?

Answer (score 0):

There are double quotes because you converted inner `dict` into string with `str(v)`. I'm not sure what you dataframe look like, but you may try `json_dict[date_range] = dup_date.to_dict(orient='records')` ?

If I guess you dataframe correctly:

```
print df
                   ArCiCo AuthorID         DptCiCo
2001-02-17   Paris_France      CCC     Tokyo_Japan
2001-03-03      London_UK      EEE  Berlin_Germany
2001-03-10  Lagos_Nigeria      BBB       London_UK
2001-03-10    Tokyo_Japan      CCC      NewYork_US
2001-03-10  Nairobi_Kenya      DDD      NewYork_US
2001-03-12   Paris_France      AAA      NewYork_US
2001-04-08   Paris_France      EEE       London_UK
2001-04-10     NewYork_US      AAA     Tokyo_Japan
```

Then you can do the following

```
dct = {dt : subdf.to_dict(orient='records') for dt, subdf in df.groupby(level=0)}

from pprint import pprint  #For printing
pprint(dct, width=100)

{'2001-02-17': [{'ArCiCo': 'Paris_France', 'AuthorID': 'CCC', 'DptCiCo': 'Tokyo_Japan'}],
 '2001-03-03': [{'ArCiCo': 'London_UK', 'AuthorID': 'EEE', 'DptCiCo': 'Berlin_Germany'}],
 '2001-03-10': [{'ArCiCo': 'Lagos_Nigeria', 'AuthorID': 'BBB', 'DptCiCo': 'London_UK'},
                {'ArCiCo': 'Tokyo_Japan', 'AuthorID': 'CCC', 'DptCiCo': 'NewYork_US'},
                {'ArCiCo': 'Nairobi_Kenya', 'AuthorID': 'DDD', 'DptCiCo': 'NewYork_US'}],
 '2001-03-12': [{'ArCiCo': 'Paris_France', 'AuthorID': 'AAA', 'DptCiCo': 'NewYork_US'}],
 '2001-04-08': [{'ArCiCo': 'Paris_France', 'AuthorID': 'EEE', 'DptCiCo': 'London_UK'}],
 '2001-04-10': [{'ArCiCo': 'NewYork_US', 'AuthorID': 'AAA', 'DptCiCo': 'Tokyo_Japan'}]}
```

If you want everything as a string, and quotes to be double ("), you can use `json.dumps`.

```
print json.dumps(dct, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

{
    "2001-02-17": [
        {
            "ArCiCo": "Paris_France", 
            "AuthorID": "CCC", 
            "DptCiCo": "Tokyo_Japan"
        }
    ], 
    "2001-03-03": [
        {
            "ArCiCo": "London_UK", 
            "AuthorID": "EEE", 
            "DptCiCo": "Berlin_Germany"
        }
    ], 
    "2001-03-10": [
        {
            "ArCiCo": "Lagos_Nigeria", 
            "AuthorID": "BBB", 
            "DptCiCo": "London_UK"
        }, 
        {
            "ArCiCo": "Tokyo_Japan", 
            "AuthorID": "CCC", 
            "DptCiCo": "NewYork_US"
        }, 
        {
            "ArCiCo": "Nairobi_Kenya", 
            "AuthorID": "DDD", 
            "DptCiCo": "NewYork_US"
        }
    ], 
    "2001-03-12": [
        {
            "ArCiCo": "Paris_France", 
            "AuthorID": "AAA", 
            "DptCiCo": "NewYork_US"
        }
    ], 
    "2001-04-08": [
        {
            "ArCiCo": "Paris_France", 
            "AuthorID": "EEE", 
            "DptCiCo": "London_UK"
        }
    ], 
    "2001-04-10": [
        {
            "ArCiCo": "NewYork_US", 
            "AuthorID": "AAA", 
            "DptCiCo": "Tokyo_Japan"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the output I have is actually what I want, I only want to remove ("   ") around the { } and the single-quote ('  '). Then produce the same output by changing single-quote (' ') around the values and replace it with the double-quotes (" ")